# Jasper iReport Designer, weekly average

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, average, designer

I am working with *iReport Designer* and want to ask how can I calculate an average sum of a column based on a date?

I am working on a report which has a database containing a table two columns: 1st is `"sample_time`" which has **DATE** values and the second is a `"watt"` which has an int value.

What I want to do is take the `"watt"` column and show it as average on the report (which I can do), and then show the same column "watt", but from averages based on the dates from the other `"sample_time"` column.

Lets say I have the dates `from 2008-01-01 to 2008-01-20` and I want to do a weekly average, lets say *from 01-01 to 01-07*, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i think this can get easily achieved using JasperReports Groups. You can create a group based on you `sample_time` column, and calculate the average for each group (which means, for each date, its just like doing a group by on a SQL query). Here there are two quick tutorials:
[JasperReports Groups](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/jasper_report_groups.htm) || [The Groups](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/groups)

Comment: Thank you Endrik, I will look at the tutorial and your suggestion and will get back at you if I managed to do it. Thank you!

Comment: Since I am a total newbie to SQL server and Jasper reporting I can't seem to find a way to do this. Right now I am using a simple query to select the two columns from my table and put them into the jasper report but I don't know if I should change the query to specific dates, as well as how to group the date and then based on a weekly, monthly group show the average stats from the other column...

Comment: I solved it, thank you. Played a lot with the SQL statement and now I have what I needed.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) . Please would you be so kind to also vote up my answear?